# Detect paragraph element change with JQuery

Tags: jquery, onchange, paragraph

Is it possible to detect if the content of a paragraph has been changed in JQuery ?

I tried the below code.

```
<p id="test">Text</p>
<button id="submit1">change</button>
```

-

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit1", function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
    $("#test").text(time);
});       
$(document).on("change", "#test", function () {
    alert("Paragraph changed");
});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nnbqye55/

I guess I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`change` events won't fire on the paragraph.  What you need are known as *Mutation Observers*.  [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is the relevant MDN documentation.  They have [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) browser penetration; for older IEs, you can probably use the deprecated *Mutation Events*, though those are known to be performance killers, so be very careful.  I'll rewrite your example using Mutation Observers; you can also check out a ***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpjhympL/4/)***:

```
$(function(){
    //Store the test paragraph node
    var test = $('#test');

    //Function to change the paragraph
    var changeParagraph = function () {
        var d = new Date();
        var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
        test.text(time);
    };

    //Bind the paragraph changing event
    $('#submit1').on('click', changeParagraph);

    //Observe the paragraph
    this.observer = new MutationObserver( function(mutations) {
        alert('Paragraph changed!')
    }.bind(this));
    this.observer.observe(test.get(0), {characterData: true, childList: true});
});
```

Comment: Do you know why there 2 `MutationRecord` ( mutations ) in the `MutationObserver`?

Comment: Because two mutations occurred.  First, the list of child nodes changed(one `text` node was replaced by another).  Second, the `data` contained within the observed DOM element changed (watch the value of `test.get(0).data` in your devtools to see what I mean).

You could only watch for `childList` changes by doing `this.observer.observe(test.get(0),{childList: true})`, but then if the data of the `text` node itself is changed *without* replacing that node, the observer wouldn't be triggered.  Best to watch for both possible mutations, then iterate through them to find the one you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'DOMSubtreeModified' to check the dom changes on html tag elements. See the support for this  [event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljfvvdnm.php#additionalEvents) across browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/nnbqye55/7/

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", "#test", function () {
    alert("Paragraph changed");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the `change()` event only to `<input>, <select>` and `<textarea>` element and detect their value change. Not on other elements.
Check [here](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

On change you have to trigger change event like below

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit1", function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
    $("#test").text(time).trigger("change");
});     

$(document).on("change", "#test", function () {
    alert("Paragraph changed");
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnbqye55/2/)**

Comment: Maybe I was clear in my query - I wanted to check for changes to the paragraph.. the change may be due to any event elsewhere...Your  solution assumes that the change is done via button click only.

Comment: My answer is help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code from here http://quiiver.appspot.com/method_observer_for_jquery
and use it like

```
$('#test').bind('text' // the method's name used to change the text
, function(){
    alert("Paragraph changed");
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nnbqye55/4) However, it works only for modifications done through jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need JQuery, in modern browsers the web API includes [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). For older browsers there are [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events).

mutation observer example:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    alert(mutation.type);
  });    
});
```

Fiddle with mutation observers: http://jsfiddle.net/nnbqye55/5/

For JQuery/older IE support, see: https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe

Answer (score 0):

The approved answer didn't work for me so here is my revised and working example for anyone looking.

```
function getNode(){
//Store the test paragraph node
var test = $('#test');

if(!test){
  // The node we need may not exist yet
  // Wait 500ms and try again
window.setTimeout(getNode, 500);
return;
}
//Function to change the paragraph
var changeParagraph = function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
    test.text(time);
};

//Bind the paragraph changing event
$('#submit1').on('click', changeParagraph);

//Observe the paragraph
this.observer = new MutationObserver(changeParagraph);
this.observer.observe(test, {characterData: true, childList: true});
});
//Delay calling our function until page loads
setTimeout(function() {
    getNode();
}, 5000);
```