# change a span class in jQuery based on page changes

Tags: jquery

I have a chat fontawesome icon currently coded as:

```
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#" class="right-bar-toggle waves-effect">
<i class="fa fa-comments "></i>
</a></li>
```

I want a span class with counter to display when new chat message arrives as follows:

```
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#" class="right-bar-toggle waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-comments "></i>
<span class="badge badge-xs badge-danger">3</span>
</a></li>
```

**3** is an example of unread chat message counter.

Selected portions of my javascript code are as follows:

```
var msgHistory = document.querySelector('#history');
var msg = document.createElement('p');
msg.innerHTML = name + ': ' + event.data;
msg.className = event.from.connectionId === session.connection.connectionId ? 'mine' : 'theirs';
```

The chat is displayed in:

```
<p id="history"></p>
```

and css are as follows:

```
#history {
     width: 100%;
     height: calc(100% - 40px);
     overflow: auto;
}

#history .mine {
    color: #07715b;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#history .theirs {
    color: #4398db;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

The chat html will display as:

```
<p id="history">
<p class="mine">Me: Hi</p>
<p class="theirs">User-1: Hello</p>
<p class="mine">Me: I am testing</p>
<p class="theirs">User-1: Okay</p>
</p>
```

1. I want to enable the span class= badge and count of `<p class="theirs">` being displayed on badge, when another user enters a message.
2. The span class= badge needs to be disabled and counter reset when `<p class="mine">` is set. That is once i enter a message.
3. The span class= badge and counter needs to display again when new message arrives on `<p class="theirs">`

How is it possible with jQuery? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is something wrong with the way i have asked my question...as i am unable see no responses. Any idea on how it is possible..???

Comment: On search i can view Detect paragraph element change with JQuery only with button click..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541004/detect-paragraph-element-change-with-jquery