# call function on change of value inside <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way in JavaScript by which I can call a function when the value of a paragraph tag is changed.

Overview:

**HTML:**

```
<p id="timer">00:00</p>
<button onclick="change()">My Button</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function change() {
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "00:01";
}

function hello() {
  alert("Hello");
}
```

I want to alert("Hello") when the value of paragraph is changed.
Something like a continuous function checking for a change in the value of paragraph.

Comment: Why couldn't you just call `hello();` from `change();`?

Comment: @b85411 I think "change();" was just meant to be an example of a DOM edit.

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Actually the paragraph is holding a timer, i want to call a function when it become 00:00, Just to illustrate as a problem, i have added another button :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27541215/1660178 see this...it is helpfull

Comment: @b0y do you have specific number when you want to fire that event or it should fire everytime it changes ?? Meanwhile you can have a look at "DOMNodeInserted" event.

Comment: Observing for mutations... do you definitely need to do it that way? I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, but there might be simpler, more efficient ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. Can you share more information?

Comment: @Ringo : I am receiving a value on load from backend which is showing time left in seconds. After calculation I am displaying the time left in minute and seconds. Now i have to manipulate the DOM when the timer is decreasing to 00:00.

Like: 
if(timer == 0)
// manipulate dom, change color, do some styling, alerts
else if (timer != 0)
// show progress bar, etc stuff

I hope you get the issue now ;)

Comment: I think the answers you've gotten for your question are good answers for what you asked, but I think MutationObserver is unnecessary for what you really need to do. If you know how much time is left in the countdown, then all you have to do is put all your styling and formatting in a function, and call that function from a setTimeout(). Say you have 90 seconds in the countdown, just do something like:

`setTimeout(function() {`

  `makeFormattingChanges();`

`}, 90000);`

`function makeFormattingChanges() {`

  `// styling and manipulation go here`

`}`

Comment: @Ringo, Yes this could be an option. But i thought of discovering some alternate ways :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `MutationObserver` with `characterData` option set to `true`

```html
<script>
  function change() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "00:01";
  }

  function hello() {
    alert("Hello");
  }
  window.onload = function() {

    var target = document.querySelector("p");

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        hello()
      });
    });

    var config = {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
      characterData: true
    };

    observer.observe(target, config);
  }
</script>

<p id="timer">00:00</p>
<button onclick="change()">My Button</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this MutationObserver API, (Check this [simple example](https://davidwalsh.name/mutationobserver-api) as well)

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        //value changed, call the other API
        hello();
    });    
});
var observerConfig = {
    characterData: true //since only the node-value needs to be checked in your case
}; 
var targetNode = document.getElementById("timer");
observer.observe(targetNode, observerConfig);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    //value changed, call the other API
    if ( mutation.type="childList" )
    {
       hello();
       //observer.disconnect();
    }
  });
});
var observerConfig = {
 childList: true
};
var targetNode = document.body;
observer.observe(targetNode, observerConfig);


document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "0.2";

window.hello = function (){
  alert(1);
}
```

```html
<p id="timer">0.0</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

One more option to do this

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = new Date().getTime();
}

var prevValue = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;

setInterval(function() {

  currValue = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;

  if (prevValue != currValue) {
    prevValue = currValue;
    hello();

  }

}, 1);

function hello() {
  alert("Hello");
}
```

```html
<p id="timer">00:00</p>
<button onclick="change()">My Button</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with onchange attribute or maybe this one can help you:

[Add event handler to HTML element using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800310/add-event-handler-to-html-element-using-javascript)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp change event is not supported for P tag

Comment: i said maybe this one CAN HELP YOU or another link!

Comment: @Tesla, thanks for the share but i was looking something like MutationObserver. 
Cheers :)