# How to use `DOMNodeInserted` - for Iframe contents to identify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

In my page, there is a iframe loads, I just want to find the element after it loads, so that I used this function:

```
$("body").on("DOMNodeInserted", ".ssueContentIframe", function() {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid red'); //works
  update();
});
```

After the `Iframe` loaded, I would like to add a event Listener to one of my element, so I would like to listen as well for that I am calling a function as `update` like above, but I am not getting the result.

What is the correct way to use the `DOMNodeInserted` for Iframe contents?
here is my try on `update` function:

```
    var update = function(){

        $(".ssueContentIframe").contents().on("DOMNodeInserted", '.ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons', function(){
            //above contents load in for loop, after loop nothing added
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');//not works
        });

    };
```

or what is the correct way, is there any plugin otherwise?
Require you kind help here!

Comment: Does the `iframe` have the same origin as parent window?

Comment: Yes, same origin only- but not works

Answer (score 0):

Note, `Mutation Events` are deprecated. You should probably utilize `MutationObserver`, see [call function on change of value inside <p> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452164/call-function-on-change-of-value-inside-p-tag/) .

To use existing `javascript` at Question, since you have already attached the event to `body` element, all nodes which are inserted at `<body>` element should be accessible at the event handler using `event.originalEvent.originalTarget` or `event.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget`. Calling `update()` to attach another `DOMNodeInserted` event at elements withing `<body>` of `iframe` `document` is not necessary.

```
$("body").on("DOMNodeInserted", ".ssueContentIframe", function(event) {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid red'); //works
  console.log(event.originalEvent.originalTarget); // inserted node
});
```

Comment: tried, Not working. contents are inserted inside the iframe by loop iteratror

Comment: What is issue with using `javascript` at Question? Note, `Mutation Events` are deprecated.  `MutationObserver` should probably be used.

Comment: I don't have knowledge with `MutationObserve` - can you update your answer with same? - very glad to you

Comment: @3gwebtrain If update Answer to `MutationObserver`, Question would be duplicate of link at Answer. Which is probably best solution. You can check where the mutation occurred using working `javascript` at Question by checking `event.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget`.