# how to find the latest modified(newly added or changed) row of html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to find the latest modified(newly added or changed) row of html table.

Comment: You can use `MutationObserver` see [call function on change of value inside <p> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452164/call-function-on-change-of-value-inside-p-tag/)

Answer (score 0):

Plain way to achieve this by maintaining a flag in latest row.

let's say flag-name/class-name  = "latest"

1) Remove all row with flag/class name latest

```
$('#resultTable tr').removeClass("latest");
```

2) when you add a new row add latest class to it

let's say newly added/modified row id is row1

```
$('#row1').addClass("latest");
```

you can get the latest row by calling.

```
var latest = $('.latest')[0];
```