# innerHTML reads span tags after javascript loads that span

Tags: javascript

Background:

I am using Django on the back end; in my template, I am using html, jinja2, and javascript (with jQuery loaded).

Goal:

I want the javascript to check every second (or so) to see if there has been an update to one part of a page, and, if there has, update another part.

Relevant html

```
<p>Last action taken: <span id="actionTime">{{ last_action_time.isoformat }}</span></p>
```

last_action_time is passed in from the view as the last time the "action_log" has been updated in the database.  So far as I can tell, it is working properly.

Relevant javascript:

```
$(function () {
    function refresh_action_log(){
        var url_actions = document.URL + ' #action_log'
        $('#action_log').load(url_actions);
    }
    function update_action_time() {
        var url_action_time = document.URL + ' #actionTime';
        $('#actionTime').load(url_action_time, function () {
            // When it loads, schedule the next request for 1s later
            setTimeout(update_action_time, 1000)
        });
        var pageUpdate = new Date(document.getElementById('updateTime').innerHTML);
        var actionUpdate = new Date(document.getElementById('actionTime').innerHTML);
        var now = new Date();
        console.log(actionUpdate.toLocaleString());  // This shows the problem
        console.log(pageUpdate.toLocaleString());
        if (actionUpdate > pageUpdate) {
            refresh_action_log();
            document.getElementById('updateTime').innerHTML = now.toLocaleString();
        };
    };
    update_action_time();
})
```

The two console.log lines are for debugging, but that has shown me the thing I don't understand.  When the page first loads, both dates print to console.  However, after the interval, the console.log(actionUpdate...) outputs "Invalid Date", whether the date has changed or not.  As far as I can tell, the reload of the actionTime does not change any formatting, etc.  If there has been no change in the date of the last action in the action_log, the display of the last_action_time does not appear any different to me.  If there has been a change in the action_log, last_action_time updates in the html.  None of this seems to make any different to the var actionUpdate; the first time it loads, it prints to console.  every time thereafter, it shows up as "Invalid Date".  This also means that the if statement never runs.

**Question:**

Why would reloading part of a page make it such that javascript <s>Date()</s> innerHTML <s>fails to read</s> reads the span tags from that part of the page, even when everything else about that part seems to be the same?

Comment: The `Date()` constructor doesn't read any part of the page.

Comment: _"Goal: I want the javascript to check every second (or so) to see if there has been an update to one part of a page, and, if there has, update another part."_ Have you tried using `MutationObserver`? See [call function on change of value inside <p> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452164/)

Comment: @Amy I think I get what you're saying.  But, since I am still learning JS, I don't know if I understand everything it implies.    Are you saying the problem is with the document.getEl... part, not the Date()?  If so, is guest271314 's solution of MutationObserver the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem in here:

```
var actionUpdate = new Date(document.getElementById('actionTime').innerHTML);
```

For reasons I still don't understand, after the initial page load, the reloading of the span then triggered the .innerHTML to read the span tags as well as the text.

solution

```
var actionUpdate = new Date($("#actionTime").text());
```