# How to make div from previous site appear on current site?

Tags: html

I have a div on page1.html with paragraphs that change. Now I want the last state of that div to appear on the next page, page2.html. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hope this simple tutorial will be helpful for you:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: this doesn't include the last set values of the page though

Comment: You might trigger change event for the paragraph.
Hope this topic will be helpful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541004/detect-paragraph-element-change-with-jquery